# vsnprintf() on Mac gives EXC_BAD_ACCESS?

Tags: c++, variadic-functions, printf

I'm not sure why I'm seeing an EXC_BAD_ACCESS in the following code:

```
template <typename ArgType>
String Format(ArgType args, ...) const {
    va_list argList;
    va_start(argList, args);

    // determine num of chars needed, don't store anything anywhere though!
    size_t charsNeeded = vsnprintf(NULL, 0, ToStdString().c_str(), argList);

    va_end(argList);

    // print formatted string into buf
    va_start(argList, args); // EDIT: new va_list here
    char buf[charsNeeded];
    vsprintf(buf, ToStdString().c_str(), argList);

    va_end(argList);

    return String(buf);
}
```

EDIT: I should probably mention that the code is supposed to be used like this:

```
String str = String("Hello, %s!").Format("World");
```

I should mention String is a small wrapper class which has a ToStdString() method which returns a std::string member var.

It's segfaulting on the vsnprintf() call, but I have no idea why!

Comment: The call to `vsnprintf` probably fails due to a mismatch between the format specifiers and the data being passed to `Format`. FWIW Variable Length Arrays (`char buf[charsNeeded]`) are not standard C++.

Comment: Did you intend to ignore using `args` for *anything* in this? ? And even if that call succeeds, the VLA is one-char short, as `charsNeeded` will not include the +1 needed for the terminator. For the sake of sanity, stuff `ToStdString()` in an actual `std::string`, then use *its* `c_str()`. I see no reason to use a VLA anyway. Use a `std::vector<>`

Comment: What do you mean "the" vsnprintf call? there are two, and if charsNeeded is too big, you may have some OS-dependent failure - could it be EXC_BAD_ACCESS on a mac?

Comment: @loreb: There is only **one** call to `vsnprintf()`, the other is a call to `vsprintf()`, note the missing `n`.

Comment: I'm not sure, but passing `NULL` as target at least looks dangerous. Allocate some buffer, pass it and see if things work better.

Comment: Unrelated: But `arglist` is invalid after `vsnprintf()` would have returned.

Comment: Actually... thinking about it, when I create the va_list from args, doesn't that exclude the "args" variable itself? I've added an example usage, perhaps someone could show how they might implement it?

Comment: @alk thanks - I did actually change my local copy of the code because of that, I'll update the question slightly (although you're right, this isn't why it's segfaulting right now!)

Comment: @Javawag vsnprintf returns the length of the string that would be printed, without the trailing NUL, so you'll need "buf[charsNeeded+1]"; btw, is there any problem with `vasprintf`?

Comment: @loreb - that makes sense, I always forget about my trailing NULs (that's why I'm not too keen on dipping down into plain C)! vasprintf() I didn't know existed, but it's not POSIX so I would prefer something reliably portable (although if it's reasonably well-implemented that would be fine!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`va_start` initialises the `va_list` to get arguments after the one specified, since in your example you are only sending one argument to the method, the `va_list` is empty.

You also need to reinitialise the `va_list` after calling `vsnprintf`.

You need to rethink the signature of your method, could do a static function:

```
class String : public std::string {
public:
    String(std::string str) : std::string(str) {}

    String(char *str) : std::string(str) {}

    static String Format(String format, ...) {
        va_list argList;
        va_start(argList, format);

        // determine num of chars needed, don't store anything anywhere though!      
        size_t charsNeeded = vsnprintf(NULL, 0, format.c_str(), argList);

        va_end(argList);
        va_start(argList, format);

        // print formatted string into buf                                           
        char buf[charsNeeded];
        vsprintf(buf, format.c_str(), argList);

        va_end(argList);

        return String(buf);
    }
};
```

**EDIT:**

If you are looking to format strings the best solutions is probably to use a `std::stringstream`: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/stringstream/

Comment: Good idea, static it is. While I'd prefer it as an instance method, I guess really static makes way more sense and means vsprintf() will just work!

Comment: Oh, one small thing though, do we need va_end(argList) before the second va_start(argList, format); ?

Comment: I added a second call to `va_end` after reading the `va_end` man page :

`Note that each call to va_start() must be matched by a call to va_end(), from within the same function.`

You should probably look at returning a `String *`, since returning a `String` means that a copy is made, for long strings this could use a lot of memory.

Comment: While this is correct, implicitly casting the result of `vsnprintf` to `size_t` is not a good idea. It returns a negative value if an error occured, and you're discarding it.